# Show/Hide Content If User Is From US With jQuery

Tags: jquery, ip

I have a Canadian site and I want to hide some content if the visitor is from the US. Is there a jQuery function that can detect IP-address's country? OR some plug-in? I don't want it to be Geo location via Google Maps API or any sort of visitor approval/verification.

In an ideal world, I'd like something similar to this:

```
if(IP == US) {
  div.hide();
}
else {
  div.show();
}
```

Comment: javascript is always _hackable_ you should do this on your server

Comment: Doesn't need to be fool proof.

Comment: Short of downloading the geoLite database and hosting it yourself, you're either going to have to use an external service or the HTML5 geoloaction API, which asks for approval ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'd normally use a service for this, and here's a function similar to the one in the question (except this one works)

```
$(function() {
    $.getJSON('http://smart-ip.net/geoip-json?callback=?', function(data) {
        if (data.countryCode == 'US') {
            $('body').text('You are in the US');
        }else{
            $('body').text("You are in " + data.countryName);
        }
    });
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/TJh4x/)

Comment: You're a BOSS! Exactly what I was looking for. I know a service is probably more efficient, but my use for this is not very strict. Meaning it's not going to make or break the site if it's not called properly. I have a fall-back.

Answer (score 0):

Without an API, you are reliant on the browser for any client information.  Since a browser is not aware of its IP's location (or even its IP), you cannot retrieve this info just through a jQuery variable.  You will need to use an API, most likely by sending the the IP address to a remote server and switching based on zip/country.

Answer (score 0):

You can use 
    
If you are using php.

I am not sure how much accurate the data is.

Comment: <?php
    echo $_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'];
    ?>